# A part of regular expression in add_rewrite_rule function not working

Tags: rewrite-rules

Consider this rewrite rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
     '^start-mcq-test/([^/]+)/(setid|topic|about)/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=start-mcq-test&lang=$matches[1]&$matches[2]=$matches[3]',
    'top'
);
```

When I browse the `http://localhost/wp-projects/mcqacademy/start-mcq-test/en/topic/dfsdfsfsfs/` url, it works well.

But when I browse the `http://localhost/wp-projects/mcqacademy/start-mcq-test/en/setid/dfsdfsfsfs/` url, it show me page not found.

What is the problem?

Comment: I just try your rewrite rule and the 2 URL works.

Comment: Still not working on my pc, tried on different browsers and also cleared cookies :(